# ng-show is not working within HAML template on Internet Explorer 7

Tags: angularjs, internet-explorer-7, coffeescript, haml, dom-manipulation

I have the following minimum failure case:

```
 %span.add-on
      - if planned_date.blank?
          %i.icon-calendar
      - else
        if successful
        %i.icon-calendar.foo
          {{showPopup}}
          .foo-popup(ng-show='showPopup')
             Show succesful
```

And a directive:

```
  MyModule.Directive.FooDirective = ->
      restrict: 'C'

      link: (scope, element, attrs) ->
          scope.showPopup = true

  MyApp.MyModule.directive 'foo', [MyModule.Directive.FooDirective]
```

This behaves as expected in Firefox, Safari, Chrome, Opera, and IE8+, displaying a styled popup with the words "Show succesfull underneath the icon, and the words if succesfull above it, also interpolating `showPopup` to `true`. However, in IE7 it displays "if successful" above the icon, and interpolates `showPopup` to `true`, but does not display the popup (same behaviour in IE10 with IE7 standards mode and browser mode: IE7).

What's causing this? And how can I fix this (absolutely minimal use case) for IE 7?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

you might find the answer in  https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/4562.

I met the same problem , we can use ng-if  instead of ng-show to do what ng-show can do.

See the document http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive:ngIf .

It work in it7.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to check this: http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/ie

Old IE has some limitation and you need a special care for them.

Comment: Am I corrent that any of `ng-*` is not working?  You may want to share your html (not haml, lets separate the concerns).